# Wordpress Woocommerce - REST API limitation to up to 100 objects

Tags: wordpress, rest, woocommerce

As the documentation of woocommerce REST API (v3) stated, by default the REST API is limited to up to 100 objects to be created, updated or deleted. 
https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#batch-update-products
I'm wondering if it is possible to remove this limitation totally or set the limit a bit higher (to 1000 or so).
Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Finally found the answer here:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/304237/increase-product-variation-limit-in-woocommerce

just add the lines below to wp-includes/functions.php

```
function wpse_rest_batch_items_limit( $limit ) {
    $limit = 1000;

    return $limit;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_rest_batch_items_limit', 'wpse_rest_batch_items_limit' );
```

Comment: What if I don't have acces to the server and the wp-includes files? Is it not possible to do it by a plugin?

Comment: This didn't work in my case, anything else that can be done?

Answer (score 3):

**Hello Try This code in function.php**

```
function update_limit_for_products( $limit, $products ) {
    $limit = 1000;

    return $limit;

}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_api_bulk_limit', 'update_limit_for_products', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: This is a woocommerce filter which would mean you need that installed and they haven't said that it is.

Comment: @UnbrandedManchester The title of the question says **woocommerce**, the body of the question links to the WC docs, and the question is *tagged* `woocommerce`. Even so, *assuming they don't have WC installed*, they can still add this filter. It won't break anything just because WC isn't there. That's not how filters work.

Comment: My bad, think this was commented when going through Review Queues